# Finding the limit of a sequence; difficult

Tags: real-analysis

I have a sequence $(a_n)$ where $a_n=\sqrt[n]{3^n +5^n +7^n}$

I have to find the limit of this sequence. By intuition I should find the limits of two sequences $(a_n)$ & $(b_n)$ such that $(a_n)\le(x_n)\le(b_n)$

Does anyone if this will be the correct way of going for it or if there is a more sophisticated way of finding the limit of $(x_n)$? Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $7^n\leqslant3^n+5^n+7^n\leqslant3\cdot7^n\implies7\leqslant\sqrt[n]{3^n+5^n+7^n}\leqslant7\cdot\sqrt[n]{3}$. Hence...

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:*
$$\sqrt[n]{3^n +5^n +7^n} = 7\cdot \sqrt[n]{\left(\dfrac37\right)^n +\left(\dfrac57\right)^n +1}.$$

Comment: Shall I find the limits inside the radical first using the sum rule which would equate to 1, then find the nth root of lim1 which would be equal to 1 and then 7lim1=7 ?

Comment: Absolutely. ${}$

Comment: It requires some argument that such letting-some-$n$s-go-to-infinity-before-others is valid in this case though.

Comment: If $a_n \to 1$ and $b_n \to 0$, then $a_n^{b_n} = e^{b_n \ln a_n} \to e^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

$$\lim x_n=\lim7\cdot \lim\sqrt[n]{\left(\dfrac37\right)^n +\left(\dfrac57\right)^n +1}$$

$$lim\sqrt[n]{\left(\dfrac37\right)^n +\left(\dfrac57\right)^n +1}=\sqrt[n]{\lim{\left(\dfrac37\right)^n +\lim\left(\dfrac57\right)^n +\lim1}}=\sqrt[n]{0+0+\lim1}=\sqrt[n]{\lim1}=1$$

So $\lim x_n=1\cdot\lim7=\lim 7=7.$

Comment: As Henning Makholm noted in comments to my answer, you cannot write in this way. See my second comment to my answer to see how it should be done.